# Javascript Count numbers in a string

Tags: javascript, string, count

I need to count numbers in a string.  The numbers are separated by spaces.
(1 2 3 4 10)  I was trying to do this by charAt by that doesnt work if the number is not a single digit.  I am relative new to JS and need some examples.  I started with this but ran into a double digit #:

```
string1 = (1 1 1 4 10)
var total = parseFloat(0);
 for(var j=0; j<string1.length; j++) {
    total += parseFloat(string1.charAt(j)); 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `string1 = (1 1 1 4 10) `<--- that is not valid. Open up the developer console, you will see an error that points it out. `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number"`

Comment: Wrap your string in quotes, then simply do `string1.match(/\d+/g).length`.

Comment: @Xufox: looks like he tries to sum the nums

Comment: [Here's a solution that tallies up the numbers as you go.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39646897/6491853)

Comment: @Jonasw In that case `string1.match(/\d+/g).map(Number).reduce((a, b) => (a + b))`.

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't accepted any of the posted answers? IMHO, you were given some good answers. Did they not solve your problem?

Comment: I still cant get any of them to give me a total.  Unless I'm not putting them into my testing platform properly.  I will look at them closer tonight.

Comment: Thanks for responding (though next time I hope you will start you message with @(my name) so that I'm alerted that I received a message. My solution's JSFiddle tallies up the numbers. What was wrong with it?

Comment: Hello? Still no answer ... ? Is there anything you need help with? What went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you need to do this way, but if this string comes from another font, you can deal with it, something like this:

```
var string1 = "(1 1 1 4 10)";
var aux = string1.replace("(","").replace(")","");
aux = aux.split(" ");
var total = parseFloat(0);
 for(var j=0; j<aux.length; j++) {
    total += parseFloat(aux[j]); 
}
console.log(total);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bggLkvxd/1/

Answer (score 0):

Create an array:

```
var arr=[1,2,3]
```

and then do:

```
var count=0;
arr.forEach(function(number){
count+=number;
}
```

Or use a string:

```
var str="1 2 3";
var arr=str.split(" ");

var count=0;
arr.forEach(function(number){
count+=parseInt(number);
}
```

Count now contains the sum of all chars

Answer (score 0):

// use method split to convert string to array and then add array items:

```
var string1 = "1 1 1 4 10", total = 0;
string1.split(" ").forEach(function(item) {
    total += +item;
});
```

Comment: +"5" equal 5, '+' before string converts it to number, so we have 0 + 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler way. First, fix string1 so it's actually a string (by adding " "s), also properly declare it with "var string". Then you could do something like this.

```
var string1 = ("1 1 1 4 10")

function addString(input) {
var sum = 0;                        //get your empty variable ready
var array1 = input.split(" ");    //split your string into an array
 for(var i=0; i<array1.length; i++) { 
array1[i] = parseInt(array1[i]);    // each new array element is integer
sum += array1[i];                   // += is operator for solve/refactor
}
return sum;
}

addString(string1);
```

Comment: Why does your function contain a parameter input that is never used? Theres no need to wrap variables into brackets (return sum) and comments are marked with // ...